# How to make an arc on the bottom of uiview like an old SpaceBar Key of keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView i need to give an arc only to the bottom left and bottom right corners of UIView like an arc, eg-like old space bar key on keyboard?

Comment: that make edges rounded i want it like a curve like a smile curve

Comment: @roshan.k Why do you tell about a space-bar key? Old-style spacebar key aren't curved IMHO

Comment: imagine a smile ...a curvy smile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this:

[image]

You can use this code:

```
NSInteger marginCurve = 30;

    UIView *example1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)];
    [example1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    UIBezierPath *curve1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [curve1 moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [curve1 addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(example1.frame.size.width, 0)];
    [curve1 addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(example1.frame.size.width, example1.frame.size.height - marginCurve)];
    [curve1 addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, example1.frame.size.height - marginCurve)
              controlPoint1: CGPointMake(example1.frame.size.width / 2, example1.frame.size.height)
              controlPoint2: CGPointMake(example1.frame.size.width / 2, example1.frame.size.height)];
    [curve1 closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *ex1Layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [ex1Layer setFrame: example1.bounds];
    [ex1Layer setFillColor: [UIColor brownColor].CGColor];
    [ex1Layer setPath: curve1.CGPath];

    [example1.layer addSublayer: ex1Layer];
    [self.view addSubview: example1];
```

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: thanks it is very close to what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear what you mean by 'eg-like old space bar key on keyboard', but it sounds like you need to make a custom drawn UIView.

You do that by:

Making a subclass of `UIView` and override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

In here you can make a custom drawing most likely using `UIBezierPath`

A BezerPath can represent a large number of shapes and forms.

Depending on what you want to draw it will look something like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     for (UIBezierPath * path in self.paths) {
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,self.color.CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
     }
```

See this [excellent tutorial on UIBezierPath](https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/)